# Will Portugual Know If I Was Deported From the UK?

Tags: uk, schengen, passports

Back in December I didn’t have a proper working visa for the UK, so I was sent back to America. Essentially, denied entry.

I’m going to Italy in March, but I stop in Portugul for the border check. If I have a totally new, fresh passport- will Portugual know I was deported? Will I run into any issues? I wasn’t banned from the UK, they just suggested I go home and try to come back but I did have my finger prints taken.

I’m going to Italy as a tourist and staying with a host family I met in September when I was there for three months, and come March I’ll be that family’s Au Pair.

Comment: What if they know? It is what it is just say the truth.

Comment: To avoid the same problem you already had in the UK, do you have the proper permission to work in Italy?

Comment: @Ally Were you actually deported, or were you denied entry on arrival in the UK? How long are you planning to stay in Italy as an au pair?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I Au Paired in September - December with no issues, and met other Americans who did the same. When I called my consult about Au Pairing they told me the tourist visa is what I use.

Comment: I also was denied entry, not deported.

Comment: They won't know. The UK does not share immigration Information with the Schengen countries.

Comment: Although it’s worth mentioning that getting a new passport doesn’t magically make previous immigration problems disappear.

Comment: @Ally All nationals of non-EU countries need a valid work permit to be allowed to work as an au pair in the Schengen area.